# PySpark - Dictionary to Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I'm looking for the most elegant and effective way to convert a dictionary to Spark Data Frame with PySpark with the described output and input.

**Input :**

```
data = {"key1" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "key2" : ["val3", "val4", "val5"]}
```

**Output :**

```
 vals  |  keys
------------
"val1" | ["key1"]
"val2" | ["key1"]
"val3" | ["key1", "key2"]
"val4" | ["key2"]
"val5" | ["key2"]
```

edit:
I prefer to do most of the manipulation with Spark.
maybe first convert it to

```
 vals  |  keys
------------
"val1" | "key1"
"val2" | "key1"
"val3" | "key1"
"Val3" | "key2"
"val4" | "key2"
"val5" | "key2"
```

Comment: start with `spark.createDataFrame(data_dict.items())`. rest would be quite simple to achieve

Answer (score 0):

First construct the Spark dataframe from dictionary items. Then [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) the `vals` and then group by the `vals` and [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) all `keys` that contain that value.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = {"key1" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "key2" : ["val3", "val4", "val5"]}

df = spark.createDataFrame(data.items(), ("keys", "vals"))

(df.withColumn("vals", F.explode("vals"))
  .groupBy("vals").agg(F.collect_list("keys").alias("keys"))
).show()

"""
+----+------------+
|vals|        keys|
+----+------------+
|val1|      [key1]|
|val3|[key1, key2]|
|val2|      [key1]|
|val4|      [key2]|
|val5|      [key2]|
+----+------------+
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {"key1" : ["val1", "val2", "val3"], "key2" : ["val3", "val4", "val5"]}

df = spark.createDataFrame(data.items(), ("keys", "vals"))
df

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *



def flatten_test(df, sep="_"):
    """Returns a flattened dataframe.
    .. versionadded:: x.X.X

    Parameters
    ----------
    sep : str
        Delimiter for flatted columns. Default `_`

    Notes
    -----
    Don`t use `.` as `sep`
    It won't work on nested data frames with more than one level.
    And you will have to use `columns.name`.

    Flattening Map Types will have to find every key in the column.
    This can be slow.

    Examples
    --------

    data_mixed = [
        {
            "state": "Florida",
            "shortname": "FL",
            "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
            "counties": [
                {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
                {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
                {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
            ],
        },
        {
            "state": "Ohio",
            "shortname": "OH",
            "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
            "counties": [
                {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
                {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
            ],
        },
    ]

    data_mixed = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_mixed)

    data_mixed.printSchema()

    root
    |-- counties: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- key: string
    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
    |-- info: map (nullable = true)
    |    |-- key: string
    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
    |-- shortname: string (nullable = true)
    |-- state: string (nullable = true)


    data_mixed_flat = flatten_test(df, sep=":")
    data_mixed_flat.printSchema()
    root
    |-- shortname: string (nullable = true)
    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- counties:name: string (nullable = true)
    |-- counties:population: string (nullable = true)
    |-- info:governor: string (nullable = true)




    data = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Cole Volk",
            "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
        },
        {"name": "Mark Reg", "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60}},
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Faye Raker",
            "fitness": {"height": 130, "weight": 60},
        },
    ]


    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data)

    df.printSchema()

    root
    |-- fitness: map (nullable = true)
    |    |-- key: string
    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)

    df_flat = flatten_test(df, sep=":")

    df_flat.printSchema()

    root
    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    |-- fitness:height: long (nullable = true)
    |-- fitness:weight: long (nullable = true)

    data_struct = [
            (("James",None,"Smith"),"OH","M"),
            (("Anna","Rose",""),"NY","F"),
            (("Julia","","Williams"),"OH","F"),
            (("Maria","Anne","Jones"),"NY","M"),
            (("Jen","Mary","Brown"),"NY","M"),
            (("Mike","Mary","Williams"),"OH","M")
            ]


    schema = StructType([
        StructField('name', StructType([
            StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
            StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
            StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
            ])),
        StructField('state', StringType(), True),
        StructField('gender', StringType(), True)
        ])

    df_struct = spark.createDataFrame(data = data_struct, schema = schema)

    df_struct.printSchema()

    root
    |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)

    df_struct_flat = flatten_test(df_struct, sep=":")

    df_struct_flat.printSchema()

    root
    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
    |-- name:firstname: string (nullable = true)
    |-- name:middlename: string (nullable = true)
    |-- name:lastname: string (nullable = true)
    """
    # compute Complex Fields (Arrays, Structs and Maptypes) in Schema
    complex_fields = dict(
        [
            (field.name, field.dataType)
            for field in df.schema.fields
            if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType
            or type(field.dataType) == StructType
            or type(field.dataType) == MapType
        ]
    )

    while len(complex_fields) != 0:
        col_name = list(complex_fields.keys())[0]
        # print ("Processing :"+col_name+" Type : "+str(type(complex_fields[col_name])))

        # if StructType then convert all sub element to columns.
        # i.e. flatten structs
        if type(complex_fields[col_name]) == StructType:
            expanded = [
                col(col_name + "." + k).alias(col_name + sep + k)
                for k in [n.name for n in complex_fields[col_name]]
            ]
            df = df.select("*", *expanded).drop(col_name)

        # if ArrayType then add the Array Elements as Rows using the explode function
        # i.e. explode Arrays
        elif type(complex_fields[col_name]) == ArrayType:
            df = df.withColumn(col_name, explode_outer(col_name))

        # if MapType then convert all sub element to columns.
        # i.e. flatten
        elif type(complex_fields[col_name]) == MapType:
            keys_df = df.select(explode_outer(map_keys(col(col_name)))).distinct()
            keys = list(map(lambda row: row[0], keys_df.collect()))
            key_cols = list(
                map(
                    lambda f: col(col_name).getItem(f).alias(str(col_name + sep + f)),
                    keys,
                )
            )
            drop_column_list = [col_name]
            df = df.select(
                [
                    col_name
                    for col_name in df.columns
                    if col_name not in drop_column_list
                ]
                + key_cols
            )

        # recompute remaining Complex Fields in Schema
        complex_fields = dict(
            [
                (field.name, field.dataType)
                for field in df.schema.fields
                if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType
                or type(field.dataType) == StructType
                or type(field.dataType) == MapType
            ]
        )

    return df

df_falt = flatten_test(df)

df_falt
```

| keys | vals |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | val1 |
| key1 | val2 |
| key1 | val3 |
| key2 | val3 |
| key2 | val4 |
| key2 | val5 |